# Ubuntu 16.04 is broken as far as our Epson printers are concerned

Tags: drivers, 16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on two computers, have not had any printing problems until I upgraded to 16.04, now not able to print.  Epson XP-960 is useless due to the release of a broken version of Ubuntu, any hope for the future?

Comment: I doubt it's the OS that's "broken." More likely, the driver broke during the upgrade, or the new Linux kernel doesn't like them.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the Epson printer definition and re-add it? Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 myself, and got very frustrated with installing the driver for my Epson ET-2550 printer. After a lot of frustration I found a way, and have written the following how-to. Follow this and I hope that it will work for you.

How to install Epson printer in Ubuntu 16.04.

1. Download scanner driver (imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.04-1.1.9.x64.deb.tar.gz) from epson      webpage, http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule. (The file contains printer drive too.)
2. Extract file in to new sub folder in Home. E.g: Home/Printer
3. Open terminal window and type;

`$ ./Print/install.sh`

This will start the install process which is written in the install.sh file.

4. Go to System Settings>>Printers. Click add printer, click on the printer name that matches your own. Now the software will do the rest, choose name for printer when prompted. Print         a test page if you like.

Side note: It is not necsesary to install lsb 3.2 in Ubuntu Xenial to make this install work.

By the way, I am new to this place so I have not worked out how all things work.